# Will my Xamarin app run on Windows XP

Tags: xamarin, windows-xp, xamarin.forms

From Xamarin documentation it is clear that Xamarin apps could be built to run on Windows 8 and Windows 10.
There are no clear indication of ability to run an app created in Xamarin on Windows XP and if so what would be the limitations, for example will Xamarin.Forms support it?

Comment: It looks like people did. Try the link! http://superuser.com/questions/841282/installing-xamarin-on-winxp

Comment: @FBaez51 this is for the studio, not for the resulting app

Comment: I don't think so. To get the latest XS installed you need .Net 4.5, which is not supported by XP. You'll be able to find an earlier version of XS but this won't have Xamarin.Forms built into it.

Answer (score 2):

No.

I have to type a much longer answer for SO to accept it, but the short answer is "NO."

Comment: thank you. Would it be possible for you to elaborate?

Comment: Windows 8 is the first version to support Metro style apps, which is what Xamarin Forms builds to on that platform.  Anything earlier does not support the UI libraries that Forms needs to run on the windows desktop.